# Coredata and Cordova in ios 10 and 11

Tags: ios, cordova, core-data, ibm-mobilefirst, ios10

The belowe code works perfectly on native environment but if I use it in a Mobile first generated app it crashes. Moreover it only happens when I compile the project with iOS 10 SDK, up to iOS 9 SDK it works fine.

Message sent to deallocated instance Core Data iOS 10 Mobile First 7.1

I'm getting the following error every time I try to execute a request through NSManagedObjectContext.

*** -[_PFArray count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1c524f060

Here's the code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *matches = [self processFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if( matches.count > 0 ){
    toReturn = (User*)[matches objectAtIndex:0];
}



where:



- (nullable NSArray*) processFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequest error:(NSError**)error{

    __block NSArray *matches = nil;

    @synchronized (self) {

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        [context performBlockAndWait:^{

            matches = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
        }];
    }

    return matches;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = _managedObjectContext;

    if ( context == nil ) {

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil) {
            _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }
    }


    return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


    NSURL *storeURL = [self getStoreURL];    
    NSError *errorMetadata = nil;

        NSError *error = nil;
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey  : NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication};

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:storeOptions
                                                           error:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: It says that you're calling **count** on a deallocated instance. The only place where I see a *count* is there : `if (matches.count > 0)` with `matches` being the result of your `processFetchRequest:error:`. So start by checking if your error object contains any information and look closely at this method.

Comment: Error is nil, matches is correctly allocated and has good data. The second it gets out the performBlockAndWait: block it is already a zombie (_NSZombie__PFArray*).

Comment: I don't know anything about Cordova but is ARC enabled ?

Comment: Actually ARC was not enabled and looking around I found Apple documentation which tells that since iOS 10 there is something new about core data with no use of ARC: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017342-CH1-DontLinkElementID_10.
Then I implemented the manual retain as indicated

Into the performBlockAndWait: block obj is fine and correctly allocated:
Right outside it is corrupted:

po obj
0x00000001c0494e60

Comment: Try to find a way to enable ARC because if you don't master manual reference counting, there are probably some places where objets are not retained/released.